# detect if DHCPOFFER has been received

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq, vlan, isc-dhcpd

The Linux box with `DHCP` client does not know beforehand if it is connected to access or trunk port, so it has to determine it somehow. So I'm thinking of the following:

1. have the box send a `DHCPDISCOVER` using untagged frames
2. if it fails to receive a `DHCPOFFER` message, try tagged frames

This assumes that there should be a process running in parallel with the `dhcp` client, and the process has to be able to:

- determine if the client has not received `DHCPOFFER` message
- configure Ethernet interface as `vlan` tagged and possibly restart `dhcp` client

I'm not sure if `isc-dhcp` or `dnsmasq` already have such capabilities, so I'm thinking of writing such a daemon. The problem for me is how to determine the `DHCPOFFER` packet.

Am I over complicating the problem, and there is easier solution?

Comment: Not in parallel with the DHCP client. Any DHCP client will interfere with your task, which is: Send DHCPDISCOVER on untagged frame; Response (DHCPOFFER)? Exit, run `dhcpclient` (which will send its own DHCPDISCOVER); Timeout?  Configure VLAN, Either loop or exit, run `dhcpclient`.

Comment: @waltinator, I was not considering my daemon to interfere the `DHCP` address assignment procedure, but rather monitor dhcp main daemon (or even just an interface for the presence of tagged DHCPOFFER message). Admittedly, there might be a race condition. Alternative you're offering makes sense too -- it could be a fairly simple bash/python script.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a solution using **tcpdump** to look for traffic coming from the default-router.

There you should see tagged or untagged frames.

Apart from that I think it depends on the network setup wether the DHCP-traffic works untagged on a trunk port.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I guess I could use `libpcap` to construct an expression to sniff interface for VLAN tags.